# Entity Framework Core - CreatedTime Got Null When Update

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to have **Created** and **Modified** fields **Automatically** with Entity Framework Core. I have found a solution in [***here***](http://benjii.me/2014/03/track-created-and-modified-fields-automatically-with-entity-framework-code-first/) and followed that.

It is working perfectly for adding data-

[image: Add Image]

But if I am trying to update data (updated time is perfect, but created time got null), then I am getting problem like this-

[image: Edit Image]

So, creating properties got lost (Set to *Null*)

My **BaseEntity** Class is like this-

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? CreatedTime { get; set; }
    public long CreatorUserId { get; set; }
    //public string CreatorIPAddress { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? LastModifiedTime { get; set; }
    public long LastModifireUserId { get; set; }
    //public string LastModifireIPAddress { get; set; }
}
```

And **DbContext** Class is like this-

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    //List all tables here
    public DbSet<Advertisement> Advertisements { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EducationResult> EducationResults { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Experience> Experiences { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JobCircular> JobCirculars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Reference> References { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Research> Researches { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ResearchDegree> ResearchDegrees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TeacherApplication> TeacherApplications { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Training> Trainings { get; set; }

    //Configure Database Settings
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        //Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=./applicationDB.db");
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        AddTimestamps();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public override int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
    {
        AddTimestamps();
        return base.SaveChanges(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
    }

    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        AddTimestamps();
        return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        AddTimestamps();
        return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
    }

    private void AddTimestamps()
    {
        var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.Entity is BaseEntity && (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified));

        /*
        var currentUsername = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(System.Web.HttpContext.Current?.User?.Identity?.Id)
            ? HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Id
            : -1;   //-1 for Anonimous
        */
        long currentUserId = -1;    //-1 for Anonimous

        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            if (entity.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).CreatedTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
                ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).CreatorUserId = currentUserId;
                //((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).CreatorIPAddress = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).CreatedTime = ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).CreatedTime;
                ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).CreatorUserId = ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).CreatorUserId;
                //((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).CreatorIPAddress = ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).CreatorIPAddress;
            }

            ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).LastModifiedTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).LastModifireUserId = currentUserId;
            //((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).LastModifireIPAddress = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
        }
    }

    public DbSet<ApplicationManagement.DbModel.Office> Office { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: I am using entity models as view models.

Comment: FWIW, you only need something like this for automatically updating a modified datetime, created can be handled must better simply with a default: `public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;`

Comment: Please post how are you querying and updating records. Above code is not showing any error as written.

Comment: Sure, adding them

Answer (score 0):

The only way this can be caused is by using entity models as view models. So you're posting an entity from a form or through an API call with a couple of properties set, but not the `CreatedTime` or `CreatorUserId`, causing them to get their default value of `null`.

You then assign those nulls to the loaded entity, overwriting them.

You can prevent this by either using viewmodels and mapping the appropriate properties to the loaded entity:

```
// somewhere in a controller
public void UpdatePerson(UpdatePersonViewModel model)
{
    var entity = Get(model.Id);

    entity.Name = model.Name;

    Save(entity);
}
```

Or doing the same with the entity instead of a viewmodel, which I don't recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, for modified state, created time will remain original created time. below is the script to get originalValue fom db

```
((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).CreatedTime = entity.Property("CreatedTime").OriginalValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need this code?

```cs
else
{
    ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).CreatedTime = ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).CreatedTime;
    ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).CreatorUserId = ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).CreatorUserId;
    //((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).CreatorIPAddress = ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).CreatorIPAddress;
}
```

Comment: I have tried them, but not working :(

So, I have removed them.


And is it your answer?

Comment: That code is irrelevant. I think you should not have to set that properties again, just at creation time.